# XPath: Selecting nodes included by an <xsl:include>

Tags: xslt, xpath

There's an XSL that includes another XSL:

```
<xsl:include href="registered.xsl"/>
```

That included file has a list of nodes:

```
<g:registered>
  <node1/>
  <node2/>
</g:registered>
```

Documentation says that "the children of the `<xsl:stylesheet>` element in this document replace the  element in the including document", so I would think that, given the include directive has worked, I can select g:registered nodes like if they always belonged to the inluding document:

```
select="document('')/xsi:schema/g:registered"
```

That returns an empty nodeset though.

However, this:

```
select="document('registered.xsl')/xsi:schema/g:registered"
```

does select what is required, but that, as I suppose, means opening the included file for the second time which doesn't seem nice to me.

So how do I select those includes without opening the file second time?

**EDIT**

Requested document structure:
Included document:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:g="http://www.sample.com/ns">

<g:registered-templates>
  <SampleTemplate/>
  <WrongTemplate/>
</g:registered-templates>

<xsl:include href="Sample Template.xsl" />
<xsl:include href="Wrong Template.xsl" />

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Including document:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:g="http://www.sample.com/ns">

<xsl:output method="text"/>

<xsl:include href="Label Registration.xsl"/>

<!-- How do I refer to just loaded inclusion without directing engine to the file again? -->
<xsl:variable name="template-names" select="document('Label Registration.xsl')/xsl:stylesheet/g:registered-templates"/>

<xsl:template match="Job">
  <xsl:for-each select="WorkItem">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="$template-names/*[local-name()=current()/@name]">
      <xsl:with-param name="context" select="." />
    </xsl:apply-templates>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>


</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Please show the structure of both main and included documents (i.e. the root elements and all nodes on the path from the root to the xsl:include (in the main document) and the g:registered node (in the included document).  Without that you are unlikely to get much help.

Comment: Ok, I just thought I presented all information that is relevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, my understanding was wrong.

The `document('')` function opens the file anyway, so it has no advantages, performance-wise, over `document('registered.xsl')`. And since it queries the *file*, not the now-modified DOM model of current document, the result does not include my includes.

And it is not possible to query DOM model of the transformation template itself, as far as I'm concerned.

Answer (score 0):

Selecting into your variable ***template-names*** queries the **transformation source document** - not your included stylesheet.
If you want to refer to g:registered-templates you have to point to the file like a second source document.

**EDIT**

I'm not really sure. but it looks like you want to create an element according to the attribute value.
In that case this [post will](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2086179/xslt-to-generate-html-tags-specified-in-xml) be interesting for you.

```
<xsl:for-each select="WorkItem">
    <xsl:element name="{Type}" >
        <xsl:value-of select="current()/@name"/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: No, it's not that simple. I was doing this trick: http://www.biglist.com/lists/xsl-list/archives/200110/msg00753.html