# XSLT to generate html tags specified in XML

Tags: xslt

So this may be a strange request but I'll give it a go. I have an xml document

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Page>
  <ID>Site</ID>
  <Object>
    <ID>PostCode</ID>
    <Type>div</Type>
    <Class>display-label</Class>
    <Value>PostCode</Value>
  </Object>
  <Object>
    <ID>PostCodeValue</ID>
    <Type>div</Type>
    <Class>display-field</Class>
    <Value>$PostCode</Value>
  </Object>
</Page>
```

and I'm using this XSL to transform it into a html page

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl"
>
  <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
      <head>
      </head>
      <body>
        <xsl:for-each select="Page/Object">
          &lt;<xsl:value-of select="Type"/>&gt;
          <xsl:value-of select="Value"/>
          &lt;/<xsl:value-of select="Type"/>&gt;
        </xsl:for-each>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

As you can see I'm trying to generate the correct html tag dependent on the type node in the xml. The problem is "<" isn't accepted in the xsl and encoding it stops it from being recognised as a tag.

Any suggestions how I'd go about this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [xsl:element](http://www.w3schools.com/XSL/el_element.asp) to create an element node in the output document.

```
<xsl:element name="{Type}" >
<xsl:value-of select="Value"/>
</xsl:element>
```

***Note***: the curly braces in the name attribute may look strange, if you aren't familiar. It is an [Attribute Value Template](http://www.dpawson.co.uk/xsl/sect2/N1575.html) used to evaluate an XPATH expression inside of an attribute declaration.

Applied to your stylesheet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl"
>
  <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
      <head>
      </head>
      <body>
        <xsl:for-each select="Page/Object">
            <xsl:element name="{Type}" >
                <xsl:value-of select="Value"/>
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: How would I populate this element with the class value

Comment: Do you mean to add a class attribute to your `div`? You can add attributes to the element in a similar fashinon with `<xsl:attribute>` (e.g. `<xsl:element name="{Type}"><xsl:attribute name="class">foo</xsl:attribute><xsl:value-of select="Value" /></xsl:attribute></xsl:element>`)

Comment: I added an answer to the question and also provided an alternative style that achieves the same result using apply-templates(more declarative) rather than nesting for-each clauses (more procedural).

Answer (score -1):

you need to wrap your "<" in a text node with disable-output-escaping like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><!-- DWXMLSource="temp.xml" -->
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">
  <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
      <head>
      </head>
      <body>
        <xsl:for-each select="Page/Object">
          <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="Type"/><xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&gt;</xsl:text>
          <xsl:value-of select="Value"/>
          <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;/</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="Type"/><xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&gt;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: XSLT 1.0 as originally published says: "It is an error for output escaping to be disabled for a text node that is used for something other than a text node in the result tree."

Comment: xsl:element would be the best way to do this but to answer the actual question you need to use the xsl:text as above.